# Saving in a DB the path of a photo chosen from the gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, movie, photo-gallery

In my app, I would allow the user to pick a photo from the gallery (or snap a photo/video with the camera).

I need to save the path in a db to retrieve it later, but I don't understand how I can do it.

** EDIT **

I didnt' resolve this issue, so now I save the images locally and I save the local path in the db.

Comment: have you tried with UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key of info dictionary returned in didfinishpicking method ?

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL should be present from ios 4.1, but in addition to this, I don't know how use it when the img is captured on the go and not chosen from the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`, but I'd assume that you use it as any other URL:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Comment: The problem wasn't in retriving the uiimage corresponding to an url, but the url corresponding to an image taken on the fly, if any. Instead, for a image taken from the gallery, UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL could work (but it's present only from ios 4.1).

Comment: @Objnewbie I don't really see the problem. If `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` is available, use it. If not just save the image locally.

Comment: indeed I save images locally, because I have to maintain compatibility respect to ios 3.1. Moreover, when the image is taken on the fly, UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL doesn't work, it has a value only for images chosen from the gallery.